# Azure File Share Implementation in .Net Core Web API

Tags: azure, upload, webapi, fileshare, iformfile

Can any one suggest how to Upload a file to Azure File Share in.Net Core Web API?
I'm using IFormFile to Upload File.

Note: I'm trying to upload Excel(*.xlsx) File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you had a look at the documentation already?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.sharefileclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet

It should look similar to this (Note: this code is not functionally, just made it up by memory)

```
    var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        Stream fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
        shareFileClient.UploadAsync(fileStream); 
        
    }
```